# How to create a floating widget that moves as the page scrolls in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to create a floating widget in the ListView.builder, which will follow the scrolled position as in many web sites or another applications.
I never saw such a widget nor can find. Can anybody share with his experience or give some good idea to how create such a widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of solution for my question.

First, Flutter already Have a widget called `Scrollbar`. You can wrap with him some scrollable widgets like:`ListView` or `GridView` etc.
It will give you a simple draggable widget with vertical axis on the right side.

**This is an example:**

```
Scrollbar(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 50,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text("Item= ${index + 1}"),),),
)
```

But you can't customize this widget's, for example `height` or `width`, and I found another custom created widget, which is added to [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages) also. The package name is [draggable_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar) and this was what I need. There are some styled widgets for scrollbar and custom one, that you can customize as you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at `FloatingActionButton` widget.

[image]

You can read more about this widget from the official documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html